# Newly created alias should be activated constantly

Tags: bash, bashrc

I add an alias to `~/.bashrc and activate it.

```
# add some helpful aliases
alias l.='ls -d .* --color=auto'
```

Activate it:

```
source .bashrc
```

It work well on current bash.

```
$ l.
ls: --color=auto: No such file or directory
.   .cups   .python_history  ...
```

Unfortunately, it refuses to work when I quit and restart the bash

```
$ l.
-bash: l.: command not found
```

It has to be activated manually again.

```
$ source .bashrc
# then it works
$ l.
ls: --color=auto: No such file or directory
.   .cups   .python_history  ...
```

What's the problem with my configuration?

Comment: Please use the following command to output the content of your `.profile` file and add it to the question: `sed -r '/^#.*/d; /^\s*($|#)/d;' ~/.profile`

Comment: It is also strange why you receive `ls: --color=auto: No such file or directory` each time. Your alias works as it is expected on my Ubuntu.

Comment: You are using Bash as your default shell ?

Comment: Try to do `(set -x; l.)`, let us know what that reports.